# Why should one use the definition for a first order homogenous differential equation?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

A first order differential equation is homogeneous if it can be written in the following way:
$$
f(x,y)dy = g(x,y)dx
$$
where $f$, and $g$ are homogeneous functions.

While an $n$'th order differential equation given by
$$
a_n(x)\frac{d^ny}{dx^n}+a_{n-1}(x)\frac{d^{n-1}y}{dx^{n-1}}+\cdots+a_1(x)\frac{dy}{dx}+a_0(x)y=g(x)
$$
is homogeneous only if $g(x) = 0$.

Personally, I feel like its more straightforward to use the general case to see if the differential equation can be made equal to zero.

The only thing that I can think of is that the general case only applies to linear differential equations. Does the case for first order cover a nonlinear differential equation as well? Does this then also mean that no differential equation of order $\ge 1$, if nonlinear, can be homogeneous? If so, is there a general case to cover that? How would you determine if such a nonlinear differential equation of order $\ge 1$ is homogeneous?

Comment: Yes, you are missing non-linear DE, but also coupled systems of, especially first-order systems.

Comment: The word homogeneous is overloaded here. When the ode is first order, the word homogeneous means something different than what it means for second or higher order ode.